# Need help parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, dynamic

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<watchlist timestamp="2013-02-04 17:38:24">
  <team name="Parent">
      <child name="ChildTeam1" team="3">
          <client mnem="c1">5</client>
          <client mnem="c2">0</client>
          <client mnem="c3">1</client>
          <client mnem="c4">1</client>
          <client mnem="c5">2</client>
          <client mnem="c6">6</client>
          <client mnem="c7">0</client>
          <client mnem="c8">0</client>
          <client mnem="c9">1</client>
          <client mnem="c10">0</client>
      </child>
      <child name="ChildTeam2" team="3">
          <client mnem="c1">6</client>
          <client mnem="c2">0</client>
          <client mnem="c3">0</client>
          <client mnem="c4">0</client>
          <client mnem="c5">0</client>
          <client mnem="c6">0</client>
          <client mnem="c7">0</client>
          <client mnem="c8">0</client>
          <client mnem="c9">0</client>
          <client mnem="c10">0</client>
      </child>
  </team>
</watchlist>
```

I need help parsing the above XML using jQuery. There are parent teams with children teams under them. My goal is to add up the total c1 for the parent team who's team id is 3... so in the example above, to get the total for c1, I'd add the 5 found in ChildTeam1 and the 6 found in ChildTeam2 go get a total of 11 for c1.

To add a twist... the mnem attribute on the client will change periodically, so I cannot hard code to filter for "c1", I have to dynamically pull that part. I do know that there will always be exactly 10 clients under a child though.

Any ideas?

The code I have so far, which does calculate the total for c1 for team 3 correctly, uses a filter for the mnem attribute (which I'm trying to get away from since the mnem changes):

```
function parseXml(data) {
var count1 = 0;
    $(data).find("child[team='3']").each(function(child) {
        count1 += parseInt($(this).find("client[mnem='c1']").text(), 10);
    });
    alert(count1); //output total c1 for team 3
}
```

---

### UPDATE - FINAL RESOLUTION BELOW

```
function parseXml(data) {
    var i = 0; 
    var mnemonic = new Array();

    //build array of the 10 mnemonics, with mnemonic as key value
    $(data).find("client").each(function(){ 
        if ( i < 10 ) {
            mnemonic[$(this).attr('mnem')] = 0; //set default count to 0
            i++;
        } else { return false; } //break .each loop
    });

    //find all children where team = 3, and add the numbers up for each client mnemonic
    $(data).find("child[team='3']").each(function() {
        for(var index in mnemonic) {
            //add to the count
            mnemonic[index] +=     parseInt($(this).find("client[mnem="+index+"]").text(), 10);
        }
    });

    //output the results
    for(var index in mnemonic) {
        $("#output").append( index + " : " + mnemonic[index] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` should always include a radix, btw: `parseInt(string,10)`

Comment: I changed it to count1 += parseInt($(this).find("client[mnem='BART_IN']").text(), 2); and it broke... did I do something incorrect?

Comment: Not if you want to parse it as a binary number.

Comment: Ah.. ok. I see now. I've updated it with the 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just having trouble change `c1` to something else? That's just a matter of editing the string in your selector:

```
function parseXml(data) {
    var count = 0,
        teamnum = 3,
        counter = 'c1';
    $(data).find("child[team="+count+"]").each(function(i,el) {
        count1 += parseInt($(this).find("client[mnem="+counter+"]").text(),10);
    });
    alert(count1); //output total c1 for team 3
}
```

Comment: no, the c1 was just an example, it could be anything... instead of c1, c2, c3, ... it could be ab1, zs3, bs20, ...

Comment: Just change the variable somewhere, then. Either make it global or (better yet) pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the mnem thing pretty easily by replacing `"client[mnem='c1']"` with `"client[" + attrname +"='c1']"`.  Was there anything else you needed?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what the attrname will be... unless there is a way to pull the names up front. I know that each child will always have the same list of clients that the other children will have. For example, if ChildTeam1 has client mnem="ab12" I know for a fact that ChildTeam2 will also have client mnem="ab12". My goal is to output something like "ab12 total = 11"

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your proposed code... the name of the attribute called "mnem" doesn't change, it's the value of that attribute that will change... so in my example "c1" could be "abd2" or "zeh123121", but there will always be mnem=""

Comment: Ah.  In that case, just go with `"client[mnem='" + mnemSelect + "']"` instead (where mnemSelect is a variable containing the string you need to find).  In essence, this is Blazemonger's answer.